# Django 1.10 patterns rewrite

Tags: django, python-3.x, wagtail

The [Wagtail docs](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.8.1/advanced_topics/settings.html?highlight=production#url-patterns) contain the following example for setting up `urls.py`:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns() # tell gunicorn where static files are in dev mode
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL + 'images/', document_root=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'images'))
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^favicon\.ico$', RedirectView.as_view(url=settings.STATIC_URL + 'myapp/images/favicon.ico'))
)
```

`patterns` is deprecated in Django 1.10. How can the last urlpatterns be rewritten to work in Django 1.10? I use python 3.5. I appreciate any help.

I've tried this:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns() # tell gunicorn where static files are in dev mode
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL + 'images/', document_root=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'images'))
    urlpatterns += url(r'^favicon\.ico$', RedirectView.as_view(url=settings.STATIC_URL + 'myapp/images/favicon.ico'))
```

but it results in the error:

```
TypeError: 'RegexURLPattern' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have converted the tuple to a `url()` instance as required. Now you just need to put it in a list.

```
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^favicon\.ico$', RedirectView.as_view(url=settings.STATIC_URL + 'myapp/images/favicon.ico')),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

In Django 1.8+, urlpatterns is just a list of urls. You can rewrite your patterns to just be a list `[]` instead of using `patterns`.